# Hardware addition to keep laptop temprature low

Tags: heat-sink

I have a laptop which does not have a graphics card, so when heavy computation processes run, all the computation has to be performed by the CPU and it's inbuilt graphics unit. Now because at times there are many tasks running side by side, the load on CPU increases and it gets hotter, and after a threshold point, it gets shutdown instantly in a fraction of second. I clean the fan every week to make sure there is no dust that blocks the passing of warm air out; but I want a better solution. What can I add to my hardware on top of the current heat sink to make sure the cooling becomes more efficient?

Please avoid answers like keep a cooling fan under laptop as a solution. Need a hardware solution if there's any.

I have a Dell 15R Inspiron core i5 Arrandale processor.

Comment: In its current form this question falls under "tech support". With a little research you should be able to find several aftermarket laptop cooling solutions and hacks such as applying new thermal paste or an under-laptop cooling pad. Laptops are tough to work inside due to space limitations. You probably just need to clean out the fans and vents internally

Comment: I'm surprised that you managed to heat your core(s)/GPU's up to > 100° C that thermal protection shuts off your computer with stock core speed settings. Did you manage to overclock your laptop or something? I find it strange that a well known manufacturer's quality control would be so terrible.

Comment: Voting to close as "technical support request".

Comment: No I didn't overclock, I just don't have separate GPU's to handle graphic processing, all of it needs to be handled to CPU. @Bennet Yeo

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut Even if you're using your integrated graphics card, it's pretty crazy that the laptop is heating itself so much. Perhaps you should install some software like [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) and confirm you're really hitting really high temps. Additionally if you really do find that your gpu is able to generate so much heat in tadem with your core, if you have a usb c connection you could purchase a desktop gpu and use a seperated graphics card to run programs.

Answer (score 1):

Laptops over time especially as they get older generate more heat as they keep up with the latest OS and software which gets more demanding.3-4 years is the lifetime I realistically expect any laptop to perform comfortably.

cooling pads don't offer much. Look into  Opolar LC05 Laptop Cooler with Vacuum Fan that attaches to the fan vent of laptop. A little better than cooling pad.

Also make sure aero theme is disabled, if  you are using windows and check on CPU usage to find which processes are using the CPU most. Disable unnecessary services and programs that start up on boot.

Answer (score 0):

If the cooling pad underneath is not sufficient- have you thought about the big and nasty option to stick a heat pipe in the CPU heat sink and attach additional heat sink to it. Probably you will be able to use the build in fan and no more than 3-4 ribs will have to be bend. There are also flattened heat pipes that will be easier to install. That might give you the additional 10-20W extra cooling.